# How do you use Data.withUnsafeMutbleBytes in Swift 3?

Tags: ios, swift

I'm trying to use this code from the Realm documentation:

```
var key = Data(count: 64)
_ = key.withUnsafeMutableBytes { bytes in
    SecRandomCopyBytes(kSecRandomDefault, 64, bytes)
}
```

On its own, this will compile. However as withUnsafeMutableBytes completes with a closure, instead of this type of code flow:

```
var key = Data(count: 64)
_ = key.withUnsafeMutableBytes { bytes in
    SecRandomCopyBytes(kSecRandomDefault, 64, bytes)
}
// do something using the encryption key
```

I want to change it to this:

```
var key = Data(count: 64)
_ = key.withUnsafeMutableBytes { bytes in
    SecRandomCopyBytes(kSecRandomDefault, 64, bytes)
    // do something using the encryption key
}
```

But I just cannot add anything else to the closure without starting to get errors, for example its not possible to simply add just a print statement:

```
    var key = Data(count: 64)
    _ = key.withUnsafeMutableBytes { bytes in
        SecRandomCopyBytes(kSecRandomDefault, 64, bytes)
        print("WTF!")
    }
```

Will give this error:

[image]

If I try to get rid of the _, then its this error:

[image]

I found this thread https://forums.developer.apple.com/thread/51439

But after trying what's in that thread, which doesn't compile actually compile, and so after applying XCode auto-corrections to, I just end up with one error after another after another after another and its driving me nuts.

Comment: There is a problem in that `SecRandomCopyBytes` may fail, that needs to be checked for.

Comment: Note: The question here seems to be how to add statements inside the closure.

Comment: @zaph And the duplicate I pointed to showed how. Now I have to repeat what that duplicate already says, which obviates the whole point of being able to mark as a duplicate.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ignoring the `SecRandomCopyBytes` part, the overall full syntax is:

```
var key = Data(count: 64)
key.withUnsafeMutableBytes { (ptr:UnsafeMutablePointer<UInt8>) -> Void in
    print("here")
}
```

Putting `SecRandomCopyBytes` doesn't seem to make any serious difference:

```
var key = Data(count: 64)
key.withUnsafeMutableBytes { (ptr:UnsafeMutablePointer<UInt8>) -> Void in
    SecRandomCopyBytes(kSecRandomDefault, 64, ptr)
    print("here")
}
```

That might not be your final code, of course, but the point is that it compiles and permits you to proceed to develop the code further. — Actually, just for laughs, I tried the following, to see whether we really were populating the Data with random bytes, and it seems to be working fine:

```
    var key = Data(count: 64)
    key.withUnsafeMutableBytes { (ptr:UnsafeMutablePointer<UInt8>) -> Void in
        _ = SecRandomCopyBytes(kSecRandomDefault, 64, ptr)
    }
    for b in key {print(b)}
```

Note the use of `_ =` to suppress the warning about the unused result.

Comment: One point: Adding the `print` statement requires changing `ptr in` to `(ptr:UnsafeMutablePointer<UInt8>) -> Void in` which is unfortunate, surprising but understandable closure syntax.

Comment: @zaph I have to wonder whether the OP has found a bug in the Swift compiler. Why should adding a second line require you to say explicitly what is obviously the case, that a Data's bytes are UInt8?

Answer (score 0):

For me declarate a count constant before worked:

```
func generateRandomBytes() -> String? {
        var keyData = Data(count: 48)
        let count = keyData.count
        let result = keyData.withUnsafeMutableBytes {
            (mutableBytes: UnsafeMutablePointer<UInt8>) -> Int32 in
            SecRandomCopyBytes(kSecRandomDefault, count, mutableBytes)
        }
        if result == errSecSuccess {
            return keyData.base64EncodedString()
        } else {
            print("Problem generating random bytes")
            return nil
        }
    }
```